# Registro anterior Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Olá estou tentando ver o registro anterior em relação ao registro atual. Estou usando o seguinte cód.

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE compoid <"Contraband" ORDER BY compoid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Mas ele está retornando a tabela em branco
O que está errado? Como eu posso pesquisar o registro anterior usando select no mysql

Comment: Qual deveria ser o valor do registro anterior em compoid? Testou com outros valores? Grande chance do problema estar nos dados.

Comment: Pelo que entendi o seu campo `compoid` seria um numérico inteiro, geralmente _auto increment_, você está comparando-o com uma string? `compoid < "Contraband"`

Comment: @KaduAmaral Você por poderia mandar um código com essa string <"contraband"? Por favor

Comment: @Bacco minha duvidas seria pegar o valor do registro anterior em relação a ultima posição de registros. Por isso o **limit 1**

Comment: Essa parte está clara pra mim, o que eu perguntei é qual seria o valor do registro anterior. Também perguntei se você testou com outros valores. Você está ordenando por Compoid por querer ordem alfabética?

Comment: @Bacco Sim ordenando por Compoid, Mas seguinte não há como eu saber qual é ultimo registro, uma vez que estou execultando tudo isso do lado cliente via queyri. Ou tem?

Comment: Eu se fosse você primeiro selecionaria todos, só com order, pra ver o que retorna. Depois poria o limit de volta, pois o problema pode estar, como já comentei, nos dados que você está testando, e não na _query_. Sua _query_ parece certa, mas como você não pôs a estrutura da tabela na pergunta, pode ser que não e pode ser que sim.

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes pra mim te enviar um código, preciso saber a modelagem da tua tabela. [Edite sua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/56090/edit) informando a modelagem da tabela e alguns valores, assim poderemos te ajudar...

Answer (score 1):

testei e deu certo abaixo ele pega o penúltimo registro da tabela

```
SELECT max(compoid)-1, t.* FROM Tabela t ORDER BY compoid DESC LIMIT 1;
```